# junitxml jenkins plugin not showing output of passed tests (PyTest)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pytest

I am running pytest tests in a Jenkins scheduled job and generating a junitxml report as the following

pytest --junitxml=report.xml

Then I am using a post build action of publish junit test result and I can see the results but I don't see output of the passed tests (Even if I check the checkbox of "Retain long standard output/error"

Anyone succeeded in showing the output of passed tests when using pytest + junitxml publisher in Jenkins ?

Comment: What output do you mean, custom prints in tests?

Comment: Yes, in my particular case during the tests I ran an external JAR and I want to have all the output of it (Even if the test passed)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? If I print stuff in tests, the output is included in JUnit report.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to Pytest that doesn't add end of line in the .xml.